# Codeigniter php selected item from drop down

Tags: php, codeigniter, drop-down-menu, selecteditem

I need to populate the drop down from a directory for which I am using:

```
$dir = 'public/files/';
$files = scandir ($dir);
echo form_dropdown('myid', $files);
```

It works fine but how can I get the selected item from the menu?
I have tried using:

```
$selected=$this->input->post('myid');
```

But it does not work. Please help.Thank you.

Comment: Can you use **Inspect Element** on the generated dropdown and verify if they have `values` attribute set?

Answer (score 2):

First get the value of the dropdown through jQuery

`var selected = $('[name="myid"] option:selected')`

Then put it in a hidden text. To get the post value of it.

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
$dir = 'public/files/';
$files = scandir ($dir);
$selected=$this->input->post('myid');

//add selected to the function
echo form_dropdown('myid', $files, $selected);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is gonna work because `scandir()` produces a **numeric array** while `form_dropdown` requires an **associative array** according to the documentation:

```
$options = array(
    'small'  => 'Small Shirt',
    'med'    => 'Medium Shirt',
    'large'   => 'Large Shirt',
    'xlarge' => 'Extra Large Shirt',
);
```

You might have to iterate through your `$files` array to convert it to an associative array and make sure that the keys are set to the proper values.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$dir = 'public/files/';
$files = scandir ($dir);
foreach($files as $file){
  $array_files[$file] = $file;
}
echo form_dropdown('myid', $array_files);
```

Basically, it creates an associative array before and passes it to the drop down. Hope it helps